# Creating a list column with Powershell for a blog site using existing site columns

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, site-column, blog

When I get the fields property for a blog list, it returns empty.

```
$SiteURL = "Blog site URL here"

$web = Get-SPWeb $SiteURL

foreach($field in $web.Fields)
{

  Write-Host $field
}
```

But when I go to site columns in site settings I see many fields with the source being the parent site.

Can someone help me with adding an existing site column to the Post list of a Blog site ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it. I referenced the parent site Web and retrieved the list from that site and added to the Posts List in Blog site